# How to prevent entry if there is a bearish divergence prior to the entry point (Pine Script V.5)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I tried creating pullback strategy with the combination RSI, EMA7 and EMA30 but having a problem with;

1. I want to enter trade only when EMA7 is above EMA30 and other conditions are met (which is working fine)
2. I want to prevent entry if there is a bullish divergence prior to entry point.
3. And the trade can be entered again after EMA7 crosses EMA30 down ----> and then crosses up again with other conditions met (don't worry about other conditions, I have it covered).
4. (however, if there is a new bearish divergence, then loop back to 2.)

I don't even know where to begin, can anyone help me
Thank you in advance,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code if you want help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this `

```
//@version=5
strategy("Pullback Strategy with RSI, EMA7, and EMA30", overlay=true)

// Inputs
rsiLength = input(14, title="RSI Length")
ema7Length = input(7, title="EMA7 Length")
ema30Length = input(30, title="EMA30 Length")
divergenceThreshold = input(1.5, title="Divergence Threshold")

// Calculate indicators
rsiValue = ta.rsi(close, rsiLength)
ema7 = ta.ema(close, ema7Length)
ema30 = ta.ema(close, ema30Length)

// Calculate bullish divergence
divergenceCondition = low[2] < low[1] and low[1] < low and rsiValue[2] > rsiValue[1] and rsiValue[1] < rsiValue
bullishDivergence = rsiValue < 70 and divergenceCondition

// Entry conditions
enterLong = ema7 > ema30 and not bullishDivergence and ta.crossover(ema7, ema30)
enterShort = ema7 < ema30 and ta.crossunder(ema7, ema30)

// Exit conditions
exitLong = ta.crossunder(ema30, ema7)
exitShort = ta.crossover(ema30, ema7)

// Strategy logic
if (enterLong)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (enterShort)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if (exitLong)
    strategy.close("Long")

if (exitShort)
    strategy.close("Short")

// Plotting
plot(ema7, color=color.blue, title="EMA7")
plot(ema30, color=color.red, title="EMA30")
plotshape(bullishDivergence, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.labelup, text="Bull Div")

// Alert
alertcondition(enterLong, title="Enter Long", message="Enter Long")
alertcondition(enterShort, title="Enter Short", message="Enter Short")
`
```